# How do I create a new object of a generic type?

Tags: java, generics

I've got this class:

```
public class A<T> {
   protected T something = new T();
   ...
}
```

Of course `new T()` is not possible. What can I do instead?

I must not change the code where the constructor of this class is called, because this is done via reflection.

Annother problem is how to get the Class object of a generic class. mymethod(A.class) worked, but now A has got the parameter T.

Comment: This is very open ended.  Can you provide more information about what you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is possible to determine the type parameter passed to A at run-time, without explicitly passing the class in to A's constructor. But as the others have asked, why would you really want to do that when you don't need to?

Comment: (It's confusing that the question uses a class name that actually matches the convention for a generic parameter name, particular as the question involves generics.)

Comment: -1 Please state all of the requirements for the answers within the question.  I read below that you are not allowed to change the code where the constructor is called.  What else aren't you allowed to change?

Comment: Voted to close. Unfortunately, this is what happens when you ask a question and leave out a critical piece of information.  By now, this question is no longer on the front page and nobody's paying attention to it.  The voted up answers were all correct given the information at the time.  Your best bet is to close this question or accept the best answer.  Then ask it again with your requirements spelled out up front.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can receive the T as a parameter of the constructor:

```
protected T something;

public A(T something) {
    this.something = something;
}
```

Or, if the goal of A is to really create new T instances, then take a factory of T as an argument:

```
protected T something;

public A(Factory<T> somethingFactory) {
    this.something = somethingFactory.newInstance();
}
```

`Class<T>` can be viewed as a `Factory<T>`, since it has a `newInstance()` method, that invokes the public no-arg constructor. But a `Factory<T>` could create new instances using something other than this constructor.

Comment: +1 The factory solution is great, but you need to use something like `class DongleFactory extends Factory<Dongle>` so you can call `new Dongle()` inside the `newInstance` method.  Otherwise, you don't end up with the same exact problem in the factory.

Answer (score 7):

You can have a constructor (or method) that takes `Class<T>` parameter and have `clazz.newInstance()`

Whenever you instantiate the object you know the type, so you have:

```
A<Foo> a = new A<Foo>(Foo.class);
```

Comment: I must not change the code where the constructor of my class is called.

Comment: 1. You should have stated this as part of your question.  2. Why does this situation exist in a class you cannot modify?  Or can you only modify parts of this?  I don't understand - is this homework?

Answer (score -1):

No. Also there's no way of specifying that `T` has a no-args constructor or is even non-abstract.

You can pass in an abstract factory, or a prototype.

Please don't use reflection!!!